# Hill cipher. Inverse Matrix

Tags: c#, encryption

I have a task to write a programm which works with Hill cipher. And it was not hard to make it cipher my message, but I just can't make it uncipher it.
If I use input data from here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_cipher
it gives the same result.

But if I change a key - it won't be able to encipher the message.

I believe the problem is caused by wrong inversing of matrix, but I'm not sure. It's kinda weird why it works OK with one key, and doesn't work with another.

```
    string alphabet_eng = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";        
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        float m11 = 0, m12 = 0, m13 = 0, m21 = 0, m22 = 0, m23 = 0, m31 = 0, m32 = 0, m33 = 0;
        float deter = 0;

        m11 = alphabet_eng.IndexOf(matrix_11.Text);
        m12 = alphabet_eng.IndexOf(matrix_12.Text);
        m13 = alphabet_eng.IndexOf(matrix_13.Text);
        m21 = alphabet_eng.IndexOf(matrix_21.Text);
        m22 = alphabet_eng.IndexOf(matrix_22.Text);
        m23 = alphabet_eng.IndexOf(matrix_23.Text);
        m31 = alphabet_eng.IndexOf(matrix_31.Text);
        m32 = alphabet_eng.IndexOf(matrix_32.Text);
        m33 = alphabet_eng.IndexOf(matrix_33.Text);

        deter = (m11 * m22 * m33 + m12 * m23 * m31 + m13 * m21 * m32) - (m13 * m22 * m31 + m12 * m21 * m33 + m11 * m23 * m32);

        deter %= alphabet_eng.Length;

        if (deter == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("deter = 0");
        }

        float a11 = 0, a12 = 0, a13 = 0, a21 = 0, a22 = 0, a23 = 0, a31 = 0, a32 = 0, a33 = 0;

        a11 = (m22 * m33 - m23 * m32);
        a12 = -1*(m21 * m33 - m23 * m31);
        a13 = (m21 * m32 - m22 * m31);
        a21 = -1 * (m12 * m33 - m13 * m32);
        a22 = (m11 * m33 - m13 * m31);
        a23 = -1 * (m11 * m32 - m12 * m31);
        a31 = (m12 * m23 - m13 * m22);
        a32 = -1 * (m11 * m23 - m13 * m21);
        a33 = (m11 * m22 - m12 * m21);

        float Ta11 = 0, Ta12 = 0, Ta13 = 0, Ta21 = 0, Ta22 = 0, Ta23 = 0, Ta31 = 0, Ta32 = 0, Ta33 = 0;

        Ta11 = a11;
        Ta12 = a21;
        Ta13 = a31;
        Ta21 = a12;
        Ta22 = a22;
        Ta23 = a32;
        Ta31 = a13;
        Ta32 = a23;
        Ta33 = a33;

        Ta11 *= deter;
        Ta12 *= deter;
        Ta13 *= deter;
        Ta21 *= deter;
        Ta22 *= deter;
        Ta23 *= deter;
        Ta31 *= deter;
        Ta32 *= deter;
        Ta33 *= deter;

        Ta11 = normalize_element(Ta11);
        Ta12 = normalize_element(Ta12);
        Ta13 = normalize_element(Ta13);
        Ta21 = normalize_element(Ta21);
        Ta22 = normalize_element(Ta22);
        Ta23 = normalize_element(Ta23);
        Ta31 = normalize_element(Ta31);
        Ta32 = normalize_element(Ta32);
        Ta33 = normalize_element(Ta33);

        Ta11 = Math.Abs(Ta11);
        Ta12 = Math.Abs(Ta12);
        Ta13 = Math.Abs(Ta13);
        Ta21 = Math.Abs(Ta21);
        Ta22 = Math.Abs(Ta22);
        Ta23 = Math.Abs(Ta23);
        Ta31 = Math.Abs(Ta31);
        Ta32 = Math.Abs(Ta32);
        Ta33 = Math.Abs(Ta33);

        Tmatrix_11.Text = Ta11.ToString();
        Tmatrix_12.Text = Ta12.ToString();
        Tmatrix_13.Text = Ta13.ToString();
        Tmatrix_21.Text = Ta21.ToString();
        Tmatrix_22.Text = Ta22.ToString();
        Tmatrix_23.Text = Ta23.ToString();
        Tmatrix_31.Text = Ta31.ToString();
        Tmatrix_32.Text = Ta32.ToString();
        Tmatrix_33.Text = Ta33.ToString();
    }

    float normalize_element(float f)
    {
        if (f >= alphabet_eng.Length)
        {
            while (f >= alphabet_eng.Length)
                f -= alphabet_eng.Length;
        }
        else if ((f + alphabet_eng.Length) < 0)
        {
            while ((f + alphabet_eng.Length) < 0)
                f += alphabet_eng.Length;

            f = alphabet_eng.Length + f;
        }

        return f;
    }
```

Kindly asking for your help.

Comment: Please post the code here, instead of giving a download link.

Comment: It is window application, so it's better to have a whole project, I think. And a code is far to long to post it here. Link does not contain any viruses.

Comment: If it is to long then think about where your problem is and only post this part - see: external links and long unreadable code will give you no answers

Comment: K, I've posted a method which counts the inverse matrix.

Comment: See Hill cipher part at [Classical Encryption Techniques in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/63432/Classical-Encryption-Techniques)

Comment: Have you verified that the determinant of the matrix you've chosen satisfies all of the conditions that are required for the inverse to be able to decrypt the ciphertext?

Comment: Yes, I believe. Could someone point me in a mistake in MY code? It would be wonderful.

Comment: When you resolve this problem I suggest you use two-dimensional arrays (`x[n,m]`) rather than *n^2* individual variables (`x11`, ..., `x33`) as it will greatly reduce (a) — the complexity of your code, (b) — the number of lines of you coffee, and (c) — the likelihood of error from copy/pasta in your code.

Comment: That was the plan. I used arrays and now my code is like two times shorter. And the problem is solved.